# Difference between Concurrent HashMap merge() and put()

Tags: java, hashmap, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I recently tumbled upon an article which stated the importance of merge method in ConcurrentHashMap performing atomic operations. Below is the link for the article:

https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2019/03/mapmerge-one-method-to-rule-them-all.html

It says that merge method either puts new value under the given key (if absent) or updates existing key with a given value (UPSERT) with explanation of this concept.
However, this is exactly what put() method does.

The get() and then put() together in ConcurrentHashMap are not thread-safe.

Please guide me to understand how is merge() taking care of this get() and put() together scenario and making operations on ConcurrentHashMap thread-safe?

Comment: Are you just skipping the fact that `merge()` takes a third parameter `remappingFunction`, which computes the new value based on the old and the new ones? `put()` simply doesn't do that (you'd have to compute the new value before calling put)

Comment: @ernest_k, Thanks for your comment. I was missing the part pointed out by Joachim Sauer in his answer below: 'One key concept of concurrent code is that two atomic operations execute one after the other don't necessary have the same effect as a single atomic operation doing the same thing.' That was the reason for confusion. Atomicity of the operations is the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One key concept of concurrent code is that two atomic operations execute one after the other don't necessarily have the same effect as a single atomic operation doing the same thing.

Let's ignore the case where the map doesn't already contain a value, since that is the less interesting one (there's still a race condition that you'd need to handle, but the other one is more interesting).

So if you already have a value for a given key, then `merge` basically becomes `put(key, mergeFunction(newValue, get(key))`.

If you implemented it that way then you could run into a very real issue of losing updates:

1. your thread executes `get(key)` and gets the current value (let's call it v1)
2. *another* thread updates the binding for key to a new value (let's call it v2)
3. your thread computes the new updated value using v1 and your argument to merge (let's call it v3)
4. your thread updates the binding for key to the newly merged value v3

Note that the update to `v2` is basically ignored (overwritten) by your code. If the map values are meant to represent counters, that means that you've basically ignored one update entirely and will get a wrong result.

What `merge` provides is a way to apply an update to an existing value without having to worry about other concurrent updates changing the value out from under you and you losing updates.

Comment: Many Thanks for this line:  `One key concept of concurrent code is that two atomic operations execute one after the other don't necessary have the same effect as a single atomic operation doing the same thing.`

Answer (score 2):

The point you are missing is that the `merge` method accepts a `BiFunction` (a *remappingFunction*) which compute the new value whereas a put blindly inserts/replaces a value.

The remappingFunction received the old and new values and using them you can perform some computation and return the new updated value.